# Wavefuntion for Wigner Crystal

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

Quantum wavefunctions of infinite variables can be written that describe certain Fractional Quantum Halls states, such as the Laughlin family of wavefucntions $ \Pi_{i<j} (z_i-z_j)^k $ that describe the the $ \frac{1}{k} $ states. However, can wavefunctions also be written that describe the called "crystal" states, that form when the electron density becomes too small, and the electrons converge to a lattice. If so, are there any fundamental differences between those of Wigner crystals and those of "observable" Fractional Quantum Hall states?

i.e. Would a hypothetical wavefunction that has maxima at the vertices of an equilateral triangle on the complex plane describe a triangular lattice Wigner crystal? What about a wavefuntion with zeroes at the vertices of an equilateral triangle?